# How put score in a quizgame in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

how can i maintain the score in my quiz game every time it change it's question it also reset the score to zero here is my method

```
 public void UserSelectTrue()
{  
    animator.SetTrigger("True");
    if (currentQuestion.isTrue)
    {
        countScore = countScore + 2;
        SetScoreText();
        Debug.Log("Correct");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Wrong");
    }     
    StartCoroutine(TransitionToNextQuestion());
}
public void UserSelectFalse()
{
    animator.SetTrigger("False");
    if (!currentQuestion.isTrue)
    {
        countScore = countScore + 2;
        SetScoreText();
        Debug.Log("Correct");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Wrong");
    }
    StartCoroutine(TransitionToNextQuestion());
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with unity3d but what happens if you define `countScore` as static? static variables are global and it will not reset unless you set 0 explicitly.

Comment: static should work fine. non-static should work if you don't change scene.

Comment: You have to give more information on what is happening in "TransitionToNextQuestion"? Is another scene loaded?

Comment: yes im reseting the scene so the other question will show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **Singleton** pattern with `DontDestroyOnload` to keep only one instance of the object between the scenes, be aware of the fact that `DontDestroyOnload` means the object won't be destroyed when a new scene loads

```
 public class ScoreManager: MonoBehaviour
 {
     private static ScoreManager_instance ;

     void Awake()
     {
         //we will make an instance if we don't have one yet
         if(!_instance)
             _instance = this ;
         //if we have an instance we don't need this one so we Destroy it
         else
             Destroy(this.gameObject) ;

          //we can keep this object between the scense with DontDestroyOnLoad
         DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject) ;
     }
 }
```